# Django webapp (on an Apache2 server) hangs indefintely when importing nltk in views.py

Tags: python, django, apache, ubuntu, nltk

To elaborate a little more from the title, I'm having issues importing nltk to use in a django web app. I've deployed the web app on an apache2 server. When I import nltk in views.py, the web page refuses to load and eventually times out after a few minutes of loading. I've installed nltk using pip. I've used pip to install a number of other python packages which I've been able to reference without issue within django.

I haven't been able to find anything solid to explain why this would be happening. Here's what I'm working with

- Server OS: Ubuntu 14.04
- Python: 2.7.6
- Django: 1.8.2
- Apache Webserver: 2.4.7

Like I said, I haven't been able to find any good reasons for this so please feel free to ask for any other information you need.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you run the nltk part of the code without Django and how much time it takes? Or just importing nltk making it unresponsive?

Comment: So I've tried two tests similar to what you mentioned. The first thing I tried was importing nltk in the python shell on the server. Imports almost immediately. The next was importing nltk in django's python shell, also imports immediately without issue. As far as the nltk code goes, I've only been trying to import the module in django. I've left my nltk code commented out in views.py.

Comment: Do you got any error message? Can you get the server log?

Comment: @EdwinLunando Unfortunately there are no errors thrown when I do this. Nothing in logs show any issues with this. Another noteworthy characteristic is if I run the django app locally on the server using `python manage.py runserver` the app doesn't exhibit this hanging problem. Could it be an issue with apache's settins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using the same web-stack as you and I had the exact same problem.

You need to set WSGIApplicationGroup to %{GLOBAL} in your site's Apache config file

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

Comment: The ``WSGIApplicationGroup`` directive is not really anything to do with running multiple Django projects on the same server. It is to do with code being run in sub interpreters. See http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Python_Simplified_GIL_State_API

Comment: @Vinay, this is exactly what the problem was with my apache configuration. Graham's answer is the one that helped me out as well although I'm glad you answered it. After I added `WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}` to my `apache2.conf` file, everything worked perfectly. I will add that I'm only running a single webapp on this server. Maybe you could edit your response to exclude the "multiple webapp" comment since this issue seems unrelated to that. We don't want to cause any confusion for future SO'ers. Many thanks to both of you!

Comment: Thanks, I've removed that from my answer :-)