# Django webapp (on an Wampserver) hangs indefintely when importing nltk in views.py

Tags: python, django, apache, nltk, wampserver

I've deployed the web app using Wampserver on a Windows Server 2012. When I import nltk in views.py, the web page refuses to load.

Add this `WSGIApplicationGroup% {GLOBAL}` in the Wampserver `htpd.config` configuration file as indicated in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30994921/13534886) and part of the problem has been resolved, but now when running the application using nltk package, the browser shows `Server Error (500)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I indicated in the question, in the `httpd.config` file it is necessary to add:

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

Additional, in views.py it is necessary to indicate Apache the path where the nltk files are, which by default are in `C:/Users/user_name/AppData/Roaming/nltk_data`, like so:

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
nltk.data.path.append('C:/Users/user_name/AppData/Roaming/nltk_data/')
```